# Pass animation controller declared in the home page of the app to a button present in navigation drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

This is the home page code:-

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> drawerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  AnimationController animationController;

  Animation<double> animation;
  bool cirAn = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
    animation = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut
        );
    //animationController.forward();
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    //animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return cirAn
        ? CircularRevealAnimation(
            centerOffset: Offset(size.height / 15, size.width / 3.5),
            animation: animation,
            child: myHomeWidget(
              themeProvider,
            ),
          )
        : myHomeWidget(themeProvider);
  }
```

i want to use the circular reveal animation for the whole app when a button in navigation drawer is clicked. In the home page there is a class called MyDrawer inside which another class named ThemeButton is there. Now when i tap on the theme button the circular reveal should happen for the whole app.

class ThemeButton

```
class ThemeButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ThemeButtonState createState() => _ThemeButtonState();
}

class _ThemeButtonState extends State<ThemeButton>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeChange = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        themeChange.darkTheme ? Icons.wb_sunny : Icons.brightness_3,
        size: 25,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        themeChange.darkTheme = !themeChange.darkTheme;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: how to pass the animation controller from the home page to the theme button class?

Comment: passing the animation controller through constructor is not working in this case

Comment: add `ThemeButton` constructor: something like `ThemeButton(this.animationController);` - what is not working in that case?

Comment: i tried but its not working

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: animation is not working

Comment: `class FooBarWidget extends StatefulWidget {
final AnimationController ctrl;

FooBarWidget(this.ctrl);

@override
_FooBarWidgetState createState() => _FooBarWidgetState();
}

class _FooBarWidgetState extends State<FooBarWidget> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return RotationTransition(turns: widget.ctrl, child: FittedBox(child: Icon(Icons.alarm)));
}
}` - use it like `child: FooBarWidget(controller)` and you will see rotating icon when calling `controller.forward()`

Comment: ok i will try and see